# Rails + Devise + Carrierwave + Carrierwave_direct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have a Rails 4 project with `devise`-generated `users`. Each `user` has an `avatar` which is uploaded to Amazon S3 via `carrierwave` (with `fog`). I'd like to implement [`carrierwave_direct`](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct#rails) as to upload the images directly to S3.

I've followed [these steps](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct#rails) until this step:

> You can generate a direct upload form like this:
>
> ```
> class AvatarController < ApplicationController
>   def new
>     @uploader = User.new.avatar
>     @uploader.success_action_redirect = new_user_url
>   end
> end
>
> <%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |f| %>
>   <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
>   <%= f.submit %>
> <% end %>
> ```

And have become confused.

So far I have:

- assumed AvatarController should be created at `app/controllers/avatar_controller` (with the same snippet as above)
- put `direct_upload_form_for @uploader` (full snippet above) into my the user "edit" form.

And I receive the error:

```
`undefined method `direct_fog_url'`
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get `carrierwave_direct` with `devise` users? An example project would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you have followed the steps

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['AWS_FOG_DIRECTORY'] # bucket name
end

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader
end

class UploaderTest < Sinatra::Base
  get "/" do
    @uploader = ImageUploader.new
    @uploader.success_action_redirect = request.url
    haml :index
  end
end
```

as well as

```
%form{:action => @uploader.direct_fog_url, :method => "post", :enctype => "multipart/form-data"}
  %input{:name => "utf8", :type => "hidden"}
  %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "key", :value => @uploader.key}
  %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "AWSAccessKeyId", :value => @uploader.aws_access_key_id}
  %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "acl", :value => @uploader.acl}
  %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "success_action_redirect", :value => @uploader.success_action_redirect}
  %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "policy", :value => @uploader.policy}
  %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "signature", :value => @uploader.signature}
  %input{:name => "file", :type => "file"}
  %input{:type => "submit", :value => "Upload to S3"}
```

These will only be applicable to you if using `storage :fog` in your image_uploader.rb or if you are using Sinatra/haml... 
Simply getting rid of the code I have put in should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error "undefined method 'direct_fog_url'" is likely because you are feeding the active record object to that method rather than the carrierwave uploader.

Find in your code where you are using "direct_fog_url" and make sure @uploader is @user.avatar and not @user.

For example, your job should look something like this:

```
def perform(user_id, key)
  user = User.find user_id
  uploader = user.avatar
  user.key = key
  user.remote_receipt_url = uploader.direct_fog_url(with_path: true)
  user.save!
end
```

Comment: did this answer help you?  If so...check it.